# Check if a class method was called

Tags: ruby

I have the following module and classes:

```
module MyModule
  def self.included base
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_reader :config

    # this method MUST be called by every class which includes MyModule
    def configure &block
      @config = {}
      block.call(@config) if block
    end
  end
end

class A
  include MyModule

  configure do |config|
    # do sth with the config
  end
end

class B
  include MyModule
end
```

Is it possible to check, if the `configure` method from the module was called? This means `A` should be fine, but `B` should throw an error, because it never called `configure`.

I tried it within the `self.included` callback, but the `configure` method gets called afterwards.

Comment: When should exception be thrown? When the process exits? How can you know that it won't be called some time in the future?

Comment: The exception should be thrown, when class B was defined. But you have a point with *How can you know that it won't be called some time in the future?*

Comment: A class can be reopened. A module can be included after a class is defined.

Comment: Hmmm, your right. Ok, then I have to decide on run time if the block was called.

Comment: My point is - you can check if the method was called. You can't check that it wasn't called, unless you have some constraint on *until when* should it be called.

Comment: Ok, can you summarize your comments in an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: If you want exception to be thrown when `B` is instantiated, then, you could check whether `B.config` is `nil` or not, in the constructor

Comment: @WandMaker that's what I meant by checking on run time

Comment: This kind of requirement to call a method seems a bit weird.  Why do you need this?

Comment: The included module can only work, if it was configured by the class in which it gets included. And because every instance share the same configuration, I thought that the check if the module has a valid configuration could be done when the class is loaded, and not every time a new instance of that class is created.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, @ndn is right, it could be called after the class has been evaluated. However, it sounds like what you want is to validate that the configure method has been called at some point within the class body definition (this will also allow any modules that have been included, to finish evaluating, so if a module include calls the configure method, it's all good as well).

The closest solution I've come up to address this situation can be found here:

https://github.com/jasonayre/trax_core/blob/master/lib/trax/core/abstract_methods.rb

The above code is an abstract methods implementation for ruby, which technically isn't what you're asking (you are talking about calling the method, abstract methods are about checking that a subclass defined it), but the same trick I used there could be applied.

Basically, I'm using ruby's trace point library to watch for the end of the class definition to hit, at which point it fires an event, I check whether the method was defined, and throw an error if not. So as long as you're calling configure from WITHIN your classes, a similar solution could work for you. Something like (not tested):

```
module MustConfigure
  extend ::ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def inherited(subklass)
      super(subklass)
      subklass.class_attribute :_configured_was_called
      subklass._configured_was_called = false

      trace = ::TracePoint.new(:end) do |tracepoint|
        if tracepoint.self == subklass #modules also trace end we only care about the class end
          trace.disable

          raise NotImplementedError.new("Must call configure") unless subklass._configured_was_called
        end
      end

      trace.enable

      subklass
    end

    def configure(&block)
      self._configured_was_called = true
      #do your thing
    end
  end
end

class A
  include MustConfigure
end

class B < A
  configure do
    #dowhatever
  end
end

class C < B
  #will blow up here
end
```

Or, you could try using the InheritanceHooks module from my library and skip the manual tracepoint handling:

```
class BaseClass
  include::Trax::Core::InheritanceHooks
  after_inherited do
    raise NotImplementedError unless self._configure_was_called
  end
end
```

Note, although I am using this pattern in production at the moment, and everything works great on MRI, because tracepoint is a library built for debugging, there are some limitations when using jruby. (right now it breaks unless you pass the jruby debug flag) -- I opened an issue awhile back trying to get tracepoint added in without having to enable debug explicitly.

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/3096

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on your structure.
It checks at instantiation if configure has been called, and will work automatically with any class on which you prepended MyModule.

It checks at every instantiation if configure has been called, but it is just checking a boolean so it shouldn't have any performance impact.

I looked for a way to undefine a prepended method for a specific class but didn't find anything.

```
module MyModule
  def self.prepended base
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_reader :config

    def configured?
      @configured
    end

    def configure &block
      @configured = true
      @config = {}
      block.call(@config) if block
    end
  end

  def initialize(*p)
    klass = self.class
    if klass.configured? then
      super
    else
      raise "Please run #{klass}.configure before calling #{klass}.new"
    end
  end
end

class A
  prepend MyModule

  configure do |config|
    config[:a] = true
    puts "A has been configured with #{config}"
  end
end

class B
  prepend MyModule
end

A.new
puts "A has been instantiated"

puts

B.new
puts "B has been instantiated"

# =>
# A has been configured with {:a=>true}
# A has been instantiated

# check_module_class.rb:27:in `initialize': Please run B.configure before calling B.new (RuntimeError)
#   from check_module_class.rb:50:in `new'
#   from check_module_class.rb:50:in `<main>'
```